# SQL Server : processing by group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following data:

```
Id     Date          Value
---------------------------
 1     Dec-01-2019      10
 1     Dec-03-2019       5
 1     Dec-05-2019       8
 1     Jan-03-2020       6
 1     Jan-07-2020       3
 1     Jan-08-2020       9
 2     Dec-01-2019       4
 2     Dec-03-2019       7
 2     Dec-31-2019       9
 2     Jan-04-2020       4
 2     Jan-09-2020       6
```

I need to group it to the following format: 1 record per month per id. If month is closed, so date will be the last day of that month, if not, the last day available. Max and average are calculated using all data until that date.

```
Id     Date          Max_Value   Average_Value 
-----------------------------------------------
1      Dec-31-2019        10           7,6
1      Jan-08-2020        10           6,8
2      Dec-31-2019         9           6,6
2      Jan-09-2020         9           6,0
```

Any easy SQL to obtain this analysis?

Regards,

Comment: And how does one know that a month "is closed"? And is a month closed for all values of Id or just specific values of Id?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You want to aggregate by month and then just take the maximum date in the month:

```
select id, max(date), max(value), avg(value * 1.0)
from t
group by id, eomonth(date)
order by id, max(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If by *closed* month you mean that it's not the last month of the id then:

```
select id, 
  case 
    when year(Date) = year(maxDate) and month(Date) = month(maxDate) then maxDate
    else eomonth(Date)
  end Date, 
  max(maxValue) Max_Value, 
  round(avg(1.0 * Value), 1) Average_Value
from (
  select *, 
    max(Date) over (partition by Id) maxDate,
    max(Value) over (partition by Id) maxValue
  from tablename
) t
group by id, 
  case 
    when year(Date) = year(maxDate) and month(Date) = month(maxDate) then maxDate
    else eomonth(Date)
  end
order by id, Date
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f6b6cdb5259f79afe825258cb73127d5).
Results:

```
> id | Date       | Max_Value | Average_Value
> -: | :--------- | --------: | :------------
>  1 | 2019-12-31 |        10 | 7.7    
>  1 | 2020-01-08 |        10 | 6.0    
>  2 | 2019-12-31 |         9 | 6.7    
>  2 | 2020-01-09 |         9 | 5.0
```